# Batch File Random Syntax Errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, debugging, testing, syntax

like I told in the question I get an unexplainable Syntax error from my Code.

I've bin searching for a program which automatically backups some saves every 5 Minutes. After I hadn't found anything which belongs to my purposes I decided to do it my own.. in Batch.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off

set name=Backup

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a.%%b,%%c)
set mytime=%mytime:~0,8%
set backupname=%name%_%date%_%mytime%

set dir1= (here comes the source directory)
set dir2= (here comes the target directory)

set countvar=1

:start

For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a.%%b,%%c)
set mytime=%mytime:~0,8%

set backupname=%name%_%date%_%mytime%
set dir2=(here comes the target directory)\%backupname%
echo Backupordner: %backupname%
ROBOCOPY %dir1% %dir2%

if "%countvar%" == "1" (
    set VarDir1=%dir2%
)
if "%countvar%" == "2" (
    set VarDir2=%dir2%
)
if "%countvar%" == "3" (
    set VarDir3=%dir2%
    rmdir /S /Q "%VarDir1%"
    set VarDir1=%VarDir2%
    set VarDir2=%VarDir3%
    set /a countvar=%countvar%-1
)
set /a countvar=%countvar%+1

@ping -n 30 localhost> nul

goto start
```

What it basically does is copying the files from the source directory into a folder, which is named after the date and time, in the target directory.

Caused by the high size of the backuped files I decided to add a feature, which deletes the third oldest save, so there are two remaining, newer save-files.

This is where the problem occurs: The first two "deletes" work properly, the third "delete" causes a syntax error. Everything runs normal after it.

Does anybody have an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Two obvious issues, `set /a countvar=%countvar%-1` should be `set /a countvar=countvar-1` or better still `set /a countvar-=1`. Similarly, `set /a countvar=%countvar%+1` should be `set /a countvar=countvar+1` or better still `set /a countvar+=1`.

Comment: If you comment out the `@echo off`, you should then be able to see the line that's causing the error. Asking us to pore through a screenful of code is not exactly the way to get the best help. Show your troubleshooting, and if you can't solve it, try to post a [MCVE].

Comment: `Waitfor` and `Choice` both offer timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another example of the `delayedexpansion` trap.

When `vardir3` is established, it has no value, so `vardir2` acquires *nothing* on the first occasion that `count=3`

On the second occasion, `var1` acquires that value so on the third occasion, you get a syntax error as `var1` is empty.

Solution: Forget `var3` entirely. In `count=3`, set `var2` to `%dir2%`.

Please search SO for the many, many articles on `delayed expansion`.

Also, you're better off using `set "var=value"` for a string assignment as it does **not** assign any trailing spaces that may be on the line.